# Moderator privileges and tag suggestions

Tags: support, moderation

Today i passed 1000 pts on SPSE and hence received moderator privileges.

I was able to accept a suggested edit in a post, but there also was a tag suggestion with tag decription, but i found no way to accept or reject this kind of suggestions.

How do i oderate tis kind of content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the FAQ](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq):

- **1000**   Vote to delete closed questions, access to moderation tools
- **1750**   Vote to approve or reject suggested tag wiki edits
- **1750**   Protect questions to prevent answers by new users
- **2000**   Vote to delete negatively voted answers and stronger question deletion votes

You can learn more about each of these by following the links [on the privileges page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges).